# Add interval to current date and dispay result in views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a field in one of my content-types that contains a interval (using the [interval module](https://www.drupal.org/project/interval)). I have configure the field so that the user can select how many years a curtain certificate should be valid.

How can I add this interval to the current year and count how many results I got using views?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module?

The other option would be to use the [Computer Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module but that could be risky as you enter PHP code into the field.